# Is it possible to create partitioned table with 'create table as' in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, table-partitioning

I am trying to create a partitioned table as follows:

```
create table archive.table1
   as table work1.table1 with no data
   partition by range (wk_date)
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "partition"
  Position: 98
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following, which is simpler and will work:

```
CREATE TABLE archive.table1 (LIKE work1.table1) PARTITION BY RANGE (wk_date);
```

Comment: Excellent!! worked like a charm.  I need this, as I am trying to automate a archive process using dynamic query.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

You need to first create the partitioned table, then you need to create the partitions. Once that is done you can do an `insert into partitioned_table select * from old_table`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.